# Custom Editor with Intellisense [Visual Studio]

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, intellisense, visual-studio-extensions

I would like to have a custom editor that interacts with the newer MEF language services (e.g. `IVsTextViewCreationListener`, `IIntellisenseController`, etc).

I'm writing a Visual Studio extension for a custom language. I have Intellisense, syntax highlighting, and code completion working for a specific file extension, but there is no single extension for this language. So I would like these features to work with any file extension. I also have a custom editor derived from `IVsEditorFactory` so I can open any file with 'Open With...'.

In `IVsEditorFactory.CreateEditorInstance` I use the `IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService` to create an `IVsTextBuffer` and `IVsCodeWindow`. This all works fine and I can open files in the editor, but I can't figure out how to have the MEF components apply Intellisense, sytnax highlighting, etc. to the custom editor.

One thing I tried...

```
public int CreateEditorInstance(uint createFlags, string documentMoniker, string physicalView,
  IVsHierarchy hierarchy,
  uint itemId, IntPtr docDataExisting, out IntPtr docView, out IntPtr docData,
  out string editorCaption, out Guid guidCommand, out int createWindowFlags)
{
  IComponentModel model = _package.GetGlobalService<SComponentModel>() as IComponentModel;
  IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService adapterService = model.GetService<IVsEditorAdaptersFactoryService>();
  ITextBufferFactoryServicebufferFactory bufferFactory = model.GetService<ITextBufferFactoryService>();
  ITextEditorFactoryServiceeditorFactory editorFactory = model.GetService<ITextEditorFactoryService>();
  IContentTypeRegistryServicetypeRegistry typeRegistry = model.GetService<IContentTypeRegistryService>();
  IContentType contentType = typeRegistry.GetContentType("ContentType");
  ITextBuffer buffer = bufferFactory.CreateTextBuffer(contentType);
  IWpfTextView view = editorFactory.CreateTextView(buffer);

  IVsCodeWindow window = adapterService.CreateVsCodeWindowAdapter(_serviceProvider);

  // Throws exception when trying to open the editor
  // "Could not find adapter for the given buffer"
  IVsTextLines lines = adapterService.GetBufferAdapter(buffer) as IVsTextLines;
  window.SetBuffer(lines);
  docView = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(window);
  docData = Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(lines);
  guidCommand = VSConstants.GUID_TextEditorFactory;
  return VSConstants.S_OK;
}
```

In the debugger I can see that my MEF components are now recognizing the new buffer and view. However, it appears that there is no way to convert an `ITextBuffer` into `IVsTextLines`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description, it seems that you want to create a custom language, which need to support Intellisense, syntax highlighting, and code completion working for a specific file extension. The following link provide a sample which support for Intellisense, syntax coloring, code completion, code snippets, custom project types and MSBuild integration.

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/IPyIntegration

> > I can see that my MEF components are now recognizing the new buffer and view, but I don't know how to put these into a IVsCodeWindow.

From the code, it uses the following method：

```
private IntPtr CreateCodeView(IVsTextLines textLines, ref string editorCaption, ref Guid cmdUI)
        {
            Type codeWindowType = typeof(IVsCodeWindow);
            Guid riid = codeWindowType.GUID;
            Guid clsid = typeof(VsCodeWindowClass).GUID;
            IVsCodeWindow window = (IVsCodeWindow)package.CreateInstance(ref clsid, ref riid, codeWindowType);
            ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(window.SetBuffer(textLines));
            ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(window.SetBaseEditorCaption(null));
            ErrorHandler.ThrowOnFailure(window.GetEditorCaption(READONLYSTATUS.ROSTATUS_Unknown, out editorCaption));
            cmdUI = VSConstants.GUID_TextEditorFactory;
            return Marshal.GetIUnknownForObject(window);
        }
```

Comment: Actually, the problem is that I want to support any extension. I have tried code similar this `CreateCodeView` method, but it doesn't seem to work on buffers that are created with the `ITextBufferFactoryService`. I'll update the question with more details.